# readgzfile and ob_end_flush

Tags: php, gzip

I'm trying to `gunzip` a xml file and save the content in a `$d` variable.
I see the file and can decompress it in a console.

But the code below seems to be wrong.
I have printed `ob_get_length` to control the output buffer. This gives me a number (i.e. 14285). But the variable $d is empty.
This is the code:

```
    $g = tempnam('/tmp','ff'); 
    echo $g;
    $b = @file_put_contents($g, $str);
    @ob_start(); 
    @readgzfile($g); 
    $d = ob_get_contents(); 
    //echo ">>>".$d.ob_get_length()."<<" ; <--- prints length i.e. 14285
    ob_end_flush();
    //ob_end_clean();
    @unlink($g);
```

Why var $d is empty? I'd expect, it should contain the same content, which I'm getting when I decompress the file in a console.